# Lua imported global and local variables with the same name

Tags: lua, scope

I have a file `module.lua` in which I have a ( or 2? ) variable(s).

```lua
-- module.lua

test = 30
local test = 20
test = 40

print("module.lua: " .. test)
```

I also have my main file:

```lua
-- main.lua

require("module")
print("main.lua: " .. test)
```

Result of `lua main.lua`:

```
module.lua: 40
main.lua: 30
```

I was playing with lua variable scopes but I no longer understand What's happening here.

**What happens when I have a Global variable and a local variable with the same name? (and then import that file in another one)**

I guess after the `local` keyword, changes to the `test` variable are no longer global, But everything happened before it is Global. **What is the use of this? why doesn't the interpreter throw an error and prevent this confusing situation?** (I'm new to lua, came from the python world)

-- Trying this clearly says that changes made to test before `local` are global:

```lua
-- module.lua

test = 30
test = 70
local test = 20
test = 40

print("module.lua: " .. test)
```

`lua main.lua` ->

```
module.lua: 40
main.lua: 70
```

Comment: It is impossible to explain why some content such as "example", "main1" that does not exist in the code appears in the final result.

Comment: Sorry @shingo , It was copied from my own files which had another names. I edited and corrected the question

Comment: This is explained in the manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.5

Comment: Thanks @shingo. The manual explains scoping in lua very well. but I still couldn't figure out what could be the use of having a **global variable** and an **in-file global** (I mean, declared as *local* but not bound to any specific block in a file) with the same name. Because when I **re-**declare a variable as *local* , I can no longer access to it's *global* instance (With My current knowledge of lua)  , just like "module.lua* in my question.

Comment: This is explained in the section "Chunks", you can understand that the file itself is also a block.